# How to increase the Node stack size past 3 megabytes

Tags: node.js, stack-overflow

As previously discussed, the option to increase the Node.js stack size is `--stack-size`. Apparently the unit is kilobytes. However, when I try any value higher than 3000, it crashes on loading. That's on Windows. People on Linux are reporting it can't go higher than 8192.

How do you increase the stack size beyond these values?

Edit: the actual max is 1 megabyte. For some reason, 3 megabytes appears to be accepted but then silently fails, whereas 2 megabytes crashes just as 4 does.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. What's the actual issue that you're trying to solve?

Comment: The actual issue that I'm trying to solve is I'm writing a program that deals with heavily recursive data and crashes with a stack overflow. (Yes, I know how to embrace the inner platform effect and write my own runtime with an emulated stack. No, I don't regard that as a good solution.)

Comment: And it's not possible to rewrite your code to iterate over the data instead? Or at least benefit from tail call optimization (using something like [`tco`](https://github.com/rsp/node-tco), or a recent Node version that supports it)?

Comment: All recursive functions can be rewritten as iterative loops + a list (manually implemented stack malloc'ed in the heap) and all iterative loops can be rewritten as recursive functions - no exceptions.

Comment: @robertklep I'm not using recursion as a funky syntax for iteration, the data is genuinely recursive, not tail recursive.

Comment: @slebetman See the parenthesized part of my first comment above? I wrote that because I knew what you were going to post. I must be psychic :)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you write your own interpreter. I'm just suggesting you write a loop. For most programmers that's not an inner platform. Heck, go back 15 years to the early 2000s and it would be considered good refactoring for "de-obfuscating" a recursive function.

Comment: @slebetman Well, it's not just one function. But I think you'd have to go back a couple of decades further than that before programmers weren't expected to know what a recursive function was!

Comment: Recursion is great, but if you need multi-MB stack sizes to accommodate it,  I would probably start looking for alternatives myself. You can try setting the maximum stack size to "unlimited", at least on Linux, using `ulimit -s unlimited`, but I gotta wonder what issues you'll run into next (given that stack space usage only increases but never decreases, AFAIK).

Comment: @rwallace No, in the industry I've only seen others getting used to recursion sometime around 2010. Even now a lot of the interns we get still don't really have a good grasp of recursion and I keep having to fix buggy functions. I'm not saying they don't teach recursion, I'm just saying the vast majority of people who write software for a living are not used to it. Nevermind the fact that almost 1/4 of all programmers I've ever met were not computer science or engineering majors. I see a lot of graphic artists being forced to become programmers.